# Is there a way to suggest user to unlock the device when receiving a video call?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, callkit

I'm receiving an incoming video-call (the app is in background), displaying system UI. When I slide to answer - call starts and there's a button to open the app. Can I somehow programmatically press this button on answering or suggest user to unlock his device without tapping app button?

Comment: I think the correct way to communicate with the user in this situation is using notifications

Comment: You mean I can send some local notification that will force the user to unlock his device?

Comment: You can never force the user to do anything but if they click on the badge they can choose to unlock it.

Comment: It's clear, but I receive a call via PushKit and additionally sending some visible notification sounds not good. So, in this case, we only have to accept such kind of IOS feature?

Answer (score 0):

Without use of a 3rd party API or a jailbroken iPhone, this is not possible. However, it would be possible to send a notification to the user to unlock their device.